# Need help modeling a palette type

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am trying to create a Palette type in Elm by following the guidelines in [Model the problem](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html) article. My first thought was to say:

```
type alias Palette = List Color
```

But this has drawbacks. A palette is a list of colors but it also must have two color, one for background and one for foreground.

My second try was to have a record type:

```
type alias Palette = 
  { bg : Color
  , fg : List Color
  }
```

this is better but how do I make sure the `fg` field is a list with at least one element?

Any hints on how to think functionally and [make illegal states unrepresentable](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a data type that represents a list with at least one element. You can define your own such list with something like this:

```elm
type NonEmptyList a = ListItem a (NonEmptyList a) | RootItem a
```

To make life easier, you could then define a few helper functions so that you can translate to and from a normal Elm `List`:

```elm
toList : NonEmptyList a -> List a
toList list =
  case list of
    RootItem x -> [x]
    ListItem x rest -> x :: toList rest

fromList : List a -> Maybe (NonEmptyList a)
fromList list =
  case list of
    [] -> Nothing
    [x] -> Just (RootItem x)
    (x::xs) -> Maybe.map (ListItem x) <| fromList xs
```

You could then define your Palette in terms of your new non-empty list.

```elm
type alias Palette = 
  { bg : Color
  , fg : NonEmptyList Color
  }
```

Now your `fg` field is always guaranteed by the compiler to have at least one value.